# Error problem with mutate() input using package 'fruclimadapt'

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a problem using the 'fruclimadapt' package with a simple data.frame.
This package allows to calculate bioclimatic indices from dates and weather data.

- I have grouped in a data.frame the variables that interest me from another data.frame more voluminous
- I then want to apply the function 'bioclim_hydrothermal(data, latitude, elevation)' from the package :

```
OBS_St_NAZAIRE_MONTOIR_fusio -> naz


Year = naz$time %>% year()
Month = naz$time %>% month()
Day = naz$time %>% day()
Tmin<-data.frame(naz$outside_temperature_min)
Tmax<-data.frame(naz$outside_temperature_max)
Tmean<-data.frame(naz$outside_temperature)
Prec<-data.frame(naz$rainfall)
RHmin<-data.frame(naz$outside_humidity_min)
RHmax<-data.frame(naz$outside_humidity_max)
u2med<-data.frame(naz$wind_speed)

z <-cbind(Tmin, Tmax,Tmean,Prec, RHmax, RHmin, u2med, Year, Month, Day)
colnames(z)=c("Tmin","Tmax","Tmean", "Prec","RHmax","RHmin","u2med","Year","Month","Day")

latitude<- 47.32
elevation <- 3

l<-bioclim_hydrotherm(z, latitude, elevation)
```

- I get an error message :

```
Erreur : Problem with `mutate()` input `N`.
x Input `N` can't be recycled to size 0.
i Input `N` is `N_n`.
i Input `N` must be size 0 or 1, not 6.
```

I don't understand where my mistake is because other functions in the package work well with my data :

```
climdata_temp<-bioclim_thermal(z, latitude)
```

The expected result is a data.frame containing all the variables calculated with the given function. (It's the first time I use this package so I don't have a visual of the final array)

Here datas for a reprex:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 
1961, 1961, 1961), Month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Day = 1:10, 
    Tmin = c(0.8, 7.6, 2.8, 5.6, 1.9, 5.9, 0.8, 5.7, 4.7, 4.9
    ), Tmax = c(11.1, 12, 8.3, 9.7, 9.8, 9, 11.4, 11.3, 10.3, 
    7.5), Prec = c(18.1, 35.7, 7.9, 0, 10.3, 3.1, 5.8, 4.3, 8.3, 
    0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(Year = c(1961, 
1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961), Month = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Day = 1:10, .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It's a recent package so I don't know if it's a bug or if the problem comes from my code...

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please consider posting your data by pasting the output of dput(data), rather than a formated table

Comment: @GuedesBF yes sorry,  I just updated my question. I hope now it's ok